# Facebook.com/offers tab - Is there any way to get offers id data?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Noticed recently that facebook has moved all the Offers data from user feed to Offers tab (under app) section.

Wondering if there's a way to get offers Ids from this tab? or perhaps any-other way to pull offers Ids for the user.

Offer can be accessed by going to www.facebook.com/offers.

Comment: just curious - why do you want to get the offer id? (e.g. what are you going to do with it if you can get it?

Comment: Trying to pull user's 'offers' at 1 place.... It was possible before, but with Facebook's latest change I can't find the way to do it. Any workaround mate? Would appreciate it!